# Select and group data from 2 datatables with linq and display the result on datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, ado.net

I have 2 `DataTable`s which contain data about employees and orders. I need to get the count of the orders associated with each employee as well as the employee's ID and name.

This SQL shows the data in the format I want it:

```
select e.EmployeeID as ID, 
       (e.LName+' '+e.FName+' '+e.MName) as 'Full name', 
       COUNT(e.EmployeeID) as 'Sales number'
from Employees as e 
join Orders as o on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FName, e.LName, e.MName
```

How can I use LINQ to get the data and display the results in a `dataGridView`?

This is my code so far:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var empSales = from emp in Shop.ShopDB.Tables["Employees"].AsEnumerable()
                   join order in Shop.ShopDB.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable()
                   on emp.Field<int>("EmployeeID") equals order.Field<int>("EmployeeID")
                   group emp by emp.Field<int>("EmployeeID");

    IEnumerable<DataRow> DataRows = empSales.SelectMany(group => group);
    List<object[]> list= DataRows.Select(dr => dr.ItemArray).ToList();

    //trying to get the final object but group's key is not available
    //because these datarows don't have that field
    var empss = DataRows.Select(d => new 
    {
       ID = d.Field<int>("EmployeeID"),
       Фамилия = d.Field<int>("Lname"),
       Имя = d.Field<int>("Fname"),
       Отчество = d.Field<int>("Mname")

    });

    EmployeesSalesGridView.DataSource = list;
}
```

[image: "Orders" table]

[image: "Employees" table]

Here is a script with some sample data:

```
create table Orders (OrderID int, CustomerNo int, OrderDate datetime, EmployeeID int)
insert into Orders select 1, 1, '2009-12-28', 2
insert into Orders select 2, 3, '2010-09-01', 4
insert into Orders select 3, 4, '2010-09-18', 4
insert into Orders select 4, 1, '2010-12-10', 2

create table Employee (EmployeeID int, FName varchar(20), LName varchar(20), MName varchar(20))
insert into Employee select 1, 'Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie'
insert into Employee select 2, 'Delta', 'Echo', 'Foxtrot'
insert into Employee select 3, 'Golf', 'Hotel', 'India'
insert into Employee select 4, 'Jacob', 'Kilo', 'Lima'
```

Comment: So what's the problem with your previous attempts?

Comment: @haldo When I try to retrieve DataRows from IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, DataRow>> groups I cant' get its key which, as think,  are the orders' number

Comment: It would help if you modified your post so the question you are asking is clear and problem information is not buried in the comments. It would also help if you removed as much unneeded code samples as possible from your post to make it easier to understand. I think these are the reasons you are getting downvoted.

Comment: @robbpriestley thank you for the advice. It's my first post here though

Comment: That's much better, thanks

Comment: But, I still have some problems understanding. It looks like you are new at this, and that's OK. But I think we need to start from the basics and agree on a SQL query that represents the data you wish to manipulate. Is this accurate: `select EmployeeID, FName, LName, MName from Employees where EmployeeID in (select distinct EmployeeID from Orders)`?

Comment: @robbpriestley Not quite. I need the data about an employee and the number of rows in the "Orders" table containing the employee's id

Comment: Well, I don't see in the code where you are singling the employee out. What line of code does that?

Comment: @robbpriestley I tried to group datarows by "EmployeID" `group emp by emp.Field<int>("EmployeeID")` in `empSales` query

Comment: In your comment above you specifically mention you "need the data about an employee." I can't read that any other way but to expect that you are referring to a **single employee**. But you can't single out an employee by grouping. Try this query and tell me if that's what you want to see: `select Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.FName, Employee.LName, Employee.MName, count(*) as OrderCount from Employee inner join Orders on Orders.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID where Employee.EmployeeID = 2 group by Employee.EmployeeID, Employee.FName, Employee.LName, Employee.MName`

Comment: @robbpriestley Sorry for misleading (I thought I knew English good enough..) and thank you for the hint. I could get the right query `select e.EmployeeID as ID, (e.LName+' '+e.FName+' '+e.MName) as 'Full name', COUNT(e.EmployeeID) as 'Sales number' from Employees as e join Orders as o on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FName, e.LName, e.MName`

Comment: Your query produces results for multiple employees, not just a single one. Is that in fact what you want? So we've established that you don't want to refer to a single employee then?

Comment: @robbpriestley Yes. And now i wonder how to write it using `LINQ`

Comment: I don't know, but I'll try to help you by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, then you want the result to contain the following columns: `EmployeeID`, `FullName`, and `SalesNumber` and to match the result from the SQL query.

In your code you have the comment:

> ```
> //trying to get the final object but group's key is not available
> //because these datarows don't have that field
> ```

You almost have the correct `Linq` query.  The problem is that you're flattening the group when you use `SelectMany`, that's why you can no longer access the group key.  There's no need to use `SelectMany` here.

Select the desired data into an anonymous object, then use it as the DataSource for the GridView:

```
var empSales = from emp in Shop.ShopDB.Tables["Employees"].AsEnumerable()
               join order in Shop.ShopDB.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable()
               on emp.Field<int>("EmployeeID") equals order.Field<int>("EmployeeID")
               group emp by emp.Field<int>("EmployeeID") into g
               select new 
               { 
                   EmployeeID = g.Key,
                   FullName = g.First().Field<string>("FName") + " " + 
                              g.First().Field<string>("MName") + " " + 
                              g.First().Field<string>("LName"),
                   SalesNumber = g.Count()
               };

EmployeesSalesGridView.DataSource = empSales.ToList();
```

Which produces the same result as the SQL query for your sample data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot! But turns out `g.First()` doesn't have `FName`, `MName` or `LName` properties so I had to use `g.First().Field<T>("FieldName")` instead and it worked out quite good. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @SteelWingSword I'm glad I could help ... I forgot to translate that part of the Linq for your DataTables.